# How to leave values already checked inside the Select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm beginner in ReactJS and I'm with a problem with Selects. I have a `Select` that renders some names with `MenuItem`.

What I need is that `Select` already comes with some names checked within the list of names. For example, the name `Van Henry` and `Ralph Hubbard` were already included in the list.

In order to know which item in the list should be marked, two arrays are compared, if the value in one is also in the other. So I mark that name in the list.

[image]

I'll show an image, I think I can explain better that way:

Here's my code I put at CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-4iksi?file=/index.js

[image]

Can someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey @bertdida, What you did worked perfectly for me. But after I saw your answer, I saw that I took a shit. I made my question wrong, I already fixed it here on StackOverflow. A thousand apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to create a new `array` from `names` that are present on `names2`. Then use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to set your `personName` state.

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    setPersonName(names.filter((name) => names2.includes(name)));
}, []);
```

[image: Edit Material demo]

Comment: That's work perfectly for me, thank you Bertidida!!!

Answer (score 0):

Update the value passed to `renderValue` prop in `<Select />`

```
<Select
  labelId="demo-mutiple-checkbox-label"
  id="demo-mutiple-checkbox"
  multiple
  value={personName}
  onChange={handleChange}
  input={<Input />}
  renderValue={(selected) => personName.join(", ")}
  MenuProps={MenuProps}
>
```

Comment: Sorry Codemax, I made my question wrong, I already fixed it here on StackOverflow. A thousand apologies

Comment: No worries about it

Answer (score 0):

`personName` is being checked to see if a value should be checked here:
`<Checkbox checked={personName.indexOf(name) > -1} />`

`personName` is initialized as an empty array here: `const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);`

`const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([...names2]);` would set all names in names2 array to be selected by default.

edit: edited after question was edited with more info

Comment: Srroy Dylance, I made my question wrong, I already fixed it here on StackOverflow. A thousand apologies

Comment: Thank you Dylance, your answer works, but at the moment, the solution from Bertdida work better for me.. Thank you